# Occam text animation

Tags: occam-pi

I'd appreciate it if someone would explain to me the principles of text animation in occam-pi. Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

You'll want to import the **`course`** library, and use **`cursor.x.y`** to move the cursor around the screen to draw, or overwrite with whitespace bits of text which will result in animation.

http://occam-pi.org/occamdoc/course.html#name-cursor.x.y

I.e., in order to move cursor to 3, 3:

```
#INCLUDE "course.module"

cursor.x.y( 3, 3, scr )

-- where scr is your screen channel
```

and then just write to the screen the usual way

```
out.string( 'asdf', 0, scr )
```

Repeat...